# Error showing view in popup MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view and tried to show it directly in a popup by clicking from a webgrid... I get the following error:

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:54751/Facturas/Save/4176?_=1534975761119 500 (Internal Server Error)

My JS code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url" : '/Facturas/GetEmployees',
                "type" : "get",
                "datatype" : "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id_docto", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "id_Proveedor", "autoWidth" : true},
                { "data": "Nombre_Archivo", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Ruta_Docto", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "id_tipo_docto", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Estatus", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Fecha", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "id_Proveedor", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/Facturas/Save/' + data + '">Editar</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "EmployeeID", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                        return '<a class="popup" href="/Facturas/Delete' + data + '">Borrar</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        $('.tablecontainer').on('click', 'a.popup', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            OpenPopup($(this).attr('href'));
        })
        function OpenPopup(pageUrl) {
            debugger;
            var $pageContent = $('<div/>');
            $pageContent.load(pageUrl, function () {
                $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('validator');
                $('#popupForm', $pageContent).removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');

            });

            $dialog = $('<div class="popupWindow" style="overflow:auto"></div>')
                      .html($pageContent)
                      .dialog({
                          draggable : false,
                          autoOpen : false,
                          resizable : false,
                          model : true,
                          title:'Actualización de Datos',
                          height : 550,
                          width : 600,
                          close: function () {
                              $dialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
                          }
                      })
            debugger;
            $('.popupWindow').on('submit', '#popupForm', function (e) {
                var url = $('#popupForm')[0].action;
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : url,
                    data: $('#popupForm').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            $dialog.dialog('close');
                            oTable.ajax.reload();
                        }
                    }
                })

                e.preventDefault();
            })
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        }
    })
</script>
```

My C# code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Save(int id)
{
    try
    {
        using (SiniestrosEntities dc = new SiniestrosEntities())
        {
            var v = dc.CAT_Doctos_Proveedores.Where(a => a.id_Proveedor == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(v);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return View("Login");
    }            
 }
```

Does anyone have an idea why it does not return my view "Save" to my Popup?

Comment: I found that you have query string like `_=1534975761119` instead of `Facturas/Save/4176`. Can you put `console.log` inside `function(data)` of `Save` anchor link to see what `id_Proveedor` contains?

Comment: your action is GET, but I didn't see where you call it from javascript side

Comment: `500 internal server error` essentially means that the server side code is failing. See whether you can add some logging to your server side code to see the exact exception.

Comment: I found the error, my model was wrong, I just changed and referred my model well and everything was corrected ...... Thanks to all